# Install child modules' 3rd party dependencies to local maven repo

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have a big maven project which has smaller child modules. I imported the project using m2e eclipse plugin and i got lots of compilation errors in eclipse.

After i built the whole project using `mvn clean install` some of the errors are gone(because maven plugin is able to find those dependencies in local repository and reference them from there), but the child modules still show lots of compilation error because the child modules' dependencies are missing from local repo. The dependencies are getting copied in a /lib folder inside target folder of child module.

Comment: If you have dependencies in lib folder of a child than this sounds like you are doing something wrong....

Comment: @khmarbaise The child modules are getting packed in one big war along with their dependencies. I want the dependencies also installed in local repo. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: please share more of your project (relevant part of your `pom.xml` files would be of big help).